# -msdata=sysv option in clang

Tags: clang, powerpc

The gcc option `-msdata=sysv` is used in System V.4 and embedded PowerPC systems. It puts small global and static data in the `.sdata` section, which is pointed to by register `r13` and puts small uninitialized global and static data in the `.sbss` section, which is adjacent to the `.sdata` section.

Is there an option in clang similar to the option `-msdata=sysv` in gcc for PowerPC?

Comment: It seems that Clang does not support the SVR-4 abi.